# Как заставить WCF-сервис принимать HTTP POST запросы?

Tags: c#, http, wcf, service

**Добрый день.**

У меня есть сервис, опубликованный на IIS'e. Я работаю с ним через прокси-класс. Как его нужно настроить (какие настройки задействовать), чтобы он научился принимать HTTP POST запрос?

Спасибо

Comment: Если прокси класс это удаленный клиент сервиса то запрос делается через WebRequest.

Comment: @cpp_user, да WebRequest. Мой вопрос в том, ЧТО и КАК нужно настроить в сервисе(или, может быть в IIS'е), чтобы он принимал HTTP POST запросы ?

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method="POST", ...]

Comment: @cpp_user, спасибо. а скажите, IIS как-то настраивать надо?

Comment: Для WCF сервиса нужно создать IIS application и настройки web.config c endpoint и все должно работать.